# Print a line only if the next line does NOT contain a particular match

Tags: grep, sed, awk

I am trying to search a log file for logged activities that did not complete.  For example, I log a "Starting activity for ID 1234..." and if successful, the next line will be "Activity 1234 Completed."

I'm trying to get the "Starting..." lines that are NOT followed by their corresponding "Completed" lines.

**Example Log File**

```
Starting activity for ID 1234
ID 1234 completed successfully
Starting activity for ID 3423
ID 3423 completed successfully
Starting activity for ID 9876
ID 9876 completed successfully
Starting activity for ID 99889
ID 99889 completed successfully
Starting activity for ID 10011
ID 10011 completed successfully
Starting activity for ID 33367
Starting activity for ID 936819
ID 936819 completed successfully
```

In this example, I would be looking for the output to be:

```
Starting activity for ID 33367
```

...because it's not followed by a "completed" line.

I've tried doing this with `grep` and `awk`, but have not had much success.  I'm assuming it can be done with one of those tools, but my `grep` and `awk` chops are not advanced.

Looking for a quick and reliable `grep` or `awk` pattern to give the results I need here.

Comment: I don't think it's easy with grep + awk, but can you explain a little bit about why are you doing that ? An output of all running activities, e.g success or not finsihed ?

Comment: @warl0ck, I'm looking for the "not finished".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an `awk` alternative:

```
awk '
  /^Starting/ { I[$5] = $0                  }
  /^ID/       { delete I[$2]                }
  END         { for (key in I) print I[key] }
' infile
```

Output:

```
Starting activity for ID 33367
```

The `I` associative array keeps track of what ids have been seen.

Comment: This works really well, as it even seems to accommodate situations where the "Starting..." and "Completed..." log lines are not adjacent/sequential.  Thanks @Thor!

Comment: Your welcome. This should work efficiently with (almost) arbitrary size input as it only ever stores the ID and lookup time is O(1).

Comment: Nice.  Only one thing: as I learned from @RobertL (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243550/135943) you don't need to assign a value to create an array element.  So instead of `I[$5] = 1`, you can just use `I[$5]`.  (You don't care about the value, you just want to make the element *exist*, and simply naming it accomplishes that.)

Comment: @Wildcard: You are right, but after reviewing the OP's question and the grep like output he is after, it is more appropriate to remember the whole line and output that at the end.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '$!N;/\n.*completed/d;P;D' <input
```

This will delete from output all input lines which are not followed by a line matching the string *completed*.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it with GNU sed:

```
sed -r 'N; /([0-9]+)\n\w+\s+\1/d; P; D' infile
```

- `N` reads one more line into pattern space.
- The match regex checks if identical ids are found, if so pattern space is deleted (`d`) and the cycle is restarted.
- If it didn't match, print out the first line in pattern space (`P`) and delete it (`D`).

Comment: I can't see anything extended here... so `-r` isn't needed, right?

Comment: @lmmx: It is needed because otherwise the capture group needs to be escaped, and the same goes for the `+` quantifier.

Comment: Ah OK! I modified it and was told it wasn't necessary, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

if your installation supports pcregrep, the multiline (-M) option comes in handy.

```
pcregrep -M -o '\AStarting activity for ID (\d+)\n(?!ID \1)' t.z
```

Starting activity for ID 33367